# Auto forward Outlook event invitations as text or Gmail-readable format without notification

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2007, events

I've searched everywhere for a solution but couldn't find anything. I've even found a [VBA script](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/forward-meeting-details-to-another-address/) that supposedly does this but it showed an error of failing to execute.

Is it possible to:

1. automatically forward all event invitations, changes, & cancellations;
2. in plain text or a format that is readable by Gmail; and
3. does not generate a notice to the original event creator?

Thanks!